# How to fix Log4J Vulnerability in Gradle Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, log4j2

I can see org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.0 Library in Gradle dependency tree for my project.

We have not added log4j version from outside. This version is coming as part of transitive dependencies from other jars or spring-boot-starter.

How to override the log4j version in Gradle?

Comment: If you haven't you aren't vulnerable. See https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot

Answer (score 4):

First, find out which log4j-related libraries you are really using, e.g. by

```
 .\gradlew dependencies --configuration=testRuntimeClasspath | find "log4j"
```

Then override them with a current version like so ([docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)), placed after the `dependencies` block:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0'
        force 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.0'
        force 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.0'
        force 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:2.17.0'
    }
}
```

You might need to add more/fewer libraries to that block depending on the results of the check in the beginning.

Since you are using Spring Boot, you can also use a [Spring-Boot-specific feature](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot) to set the Log4J version:

```
ext['log4j2.version'] = '2.17.0'
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not forcing the upgrades INSIDE a dependency.
I can still see with `gradlew dependencies` that there are older versions

Comment: This method works specifically for transitive dependencies, too.

Comment: how should look this for a build.gradle.kts / KotlinDSL?   at least for me it wasn't :-(

Comment: I fixed it differently, it works now in my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70367520/863403

Answer (score 2):

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html constrains are preferred.
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#rich-version-constraints
- https://blog.gradle.org/log4j-vulnerability

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api') {
            version {
                strictly('[2.17, 3[')
                prefer('2.17.0')
            }
            because('CVE-2021-44228, CVE-2021-45046, CVE-2021-45105: Log4j vulnerable to remote code execution and other critical security vulnerabilities')
        }

        implementation('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core') {
            version {
                strictly('[2.17, 3[')
                prefer('2.17.0')
            }
            because('CVE-2021-44228, CVE-2021-45046, CVE-2021-45105: Log4j vulnerable to remote code execution and other critical security vulnerabilities')
        }

        implementation('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl') {
            version {
                strictly('[2.17, 3[')
                prefer('2.17.0')
            }
            because('CVE-2021-44228, CVE-2021-45046, CVE-2021-45105: Log4j vulnerable to remote code execution and other critical security vulnerabilities')
        }

        implementation('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web') {
            version {
                strictly('[2.17, 3[')
                prefer('2.17.0')
            }
            because('CVE-2021-44228, CVE-2021-45046, CVE-2021-45105: Log4j vulnerable to remote code execution and other critical security vulnerabilities')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MacOS and using subprojects:

First I run: `./gradlew projects` which will list my subprojects:

The output:

```
:projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'test-backend'
+--- Project ':test-suite'
+--- Project ':test-suite-services'
\--- Project ':test-utils'
```

Using the output we can one by one check for dependencies:

```
./gradlew test-suite:dependencies | grep "log4j"
./gradlew test-suite-services:dependencies | grep "log4j"
./gradlew test-utils:dependencies | grep "log4j"
```