# Update 2 dependencies in the same group with gradle configuration.all

Tags: kotlin, gradle, log4j, logback, gradle-kotlin-dsl

As we want to solve (easily) all the log4j / logback vulnerabilites we tried to add configuration.all in our `build.gradle.kts`

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.apache.logging.log4j" && requested.version!! < "2.16.0") {
            useVersion("2.16.0")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
        if (requested.group == "ch.qos.logback" && requested.name == "logback-classic" && requested.version!! < "1.2.8") {
            useVersion("1.2.8")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
        if (requested.group == "ch.qos.logback" && requested.name == "logback-core" && requested.version!! < "1.2.8") {
            useVersion("1.2.8")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
    }
}
```

But it only changes the `logback-core` but not the `logback-classic`

(if I remove the `logback-core` it's  working for the classic....

Comment: You could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70364812/1005481).

Comment: will check, thanks @barfuin

Comment: unfortunately not working :-( @barfuin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little bit stupid now.

you have to use `<=` the versions, not `<`

Than it works as expected

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.apache.logging.log4j" && requested.version!! <= "2.16.0") {
            useVersion("2.16.0")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
        if (requested.group == "ch.qos.logback" && requested.name == "logback-classic" && requested.version!! <= "1.2.8") {
            useVersion("1.2.8")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
        if (requested.group == "ch.qos.logback" && requested.name == "logback-core" && requested.version!! <= "1.2.8") {
            useVersion("1.2.8")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
    }
}
```

you can even make it simpler:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.apache.logging.log4j" && requested.version!! <= "2.16.0") {
            useVersion("2.16.0")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
        if (requested.group == "ch.qos.logback" && requested.version!! <= "1.2.8") {
            useVersion("1.2.8")
            because("To avoid RCE vulnerability.")
        }
    }
}
```